# How to serialize/deserialize an object to avro in c#

Tags: c#, avro, avro-tools

I was using json.net to serialize/deserialize a pojo class to json and then send it to rabbitmq.Now I want to do the same using binary data in apache avro format.How is it possible to serialize/deserialize an object in c# ?

```
public class person
{
    public string FirstName   {  get;     set;   }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public byte[] toAvro()
    {

    }

    public void fromAvro(byte[] input)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions. Have you tried searching for `c# avro` in SO, or `avro` in NuGet? There are at least 36 packages in NuGet with `Avro` in their name.

Answer (score 0):

The below code good for your problem.

```
byte[] avroFileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
Dictionary<string, object> result = AvroConvert.Deserialize(avroFileContent);

//or if u know the model of the data
person(Your Type) result = AvroConvert.Deserialize<MyModel>(avroFileContent);
```

Comment: I encountered some problems with this library and looking for an official or reliable solution.

Comment: Apache.Avro is the official Apache NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.Avro/. It is identified as such in the C# README in the official Apache Avro GitHub project: https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/csharp/README.md. Unfortunately, there's not much as far as good how-to documentation for the C# library at this time. If you are familiar with the Java library, you will probably be able to pick it up fairly quickly.